# Keeping iCloud files resident on an iOS device

Tags: ios, ipad, icloud

Is it possible to have all files in a iCloud folder always downloaded to an iOS device? Similar to the way Dropbox, Sync.com and other cloud providers operate.  I have an iPad that I want the files in a certain folder to always be resident on the device. I often am in a situation where I need files from that folder but do not have network access....

Thanks in advance